# On-premise alternative for AWS QLDB

Tags: database, amazon, cryptography

What is the best alternative for on-premise solution with the same features as **Quantum Ledger Database** - [AWS QLDB](https://aws.amazon.com/qldb/)?

- transparent,
- immutable,
- and cryptographically **verifiable** transaction log
- owned by a **central** authority

Comment: Maybe fluree? (www.flur.ee)

Comment: These can be considered as alternative 1. Immudb
2. Oracle Immutable Tables 3. Datomic
4. EventStoreDB

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Oracle Database 19c with 19.10 release update supports native blockchain tables on-premises (as well as in the cloud). For details on the features listed and much more, see [Oracle's blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/blockchain/native-blockchain-tables-extend-oracle-database%e2%80%99s-multi-model-converged-architecture1) for more details.